# How to Prevent Jquery Slide Toggle Hiding Navigation

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, slidetoggle

My mobile menu works great with slide toggle. The menu is hidden by default, however, when i show the menu and close it in mobile view, then resize the window to show the desktop menu it doesnt appear. The navigation is still hidden despite my efforts to show it?

```
$(document).ready(function() { //MENU CONTROL
       $('.open-nav').click(function() {
               $('.menu').slideToggle('slow, swing');
               $('.downarrow').toggleClass('flip');
       });
   });

$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
      $('.menu').toggleClass('show');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, actually you need to check window resize

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
      $('.menu').toggleClass('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: even with these changes, its still hidden?

Comment: Can you check with width of window

Comment: same issue when wrapped in document.ready, ive checked with width of window, the jquery just seems to be ignored

Comment: solved the problem by adding !important to style:block in the .menu media query, not the best solution im assuming, however, it works

Comment: So you can add this css .menu.show { display: block; }